# Point subdomain to Wordpress with primary domain hosted

Tags: domain, wordpress, subdomain

I want to purchase a domain. I want the subdomain blog.example.com to blog hosted on Wordpress.com, but I don't want to host my primary domain example.com for now.

Contacted GoDaddy and BigRock for this and received different responses. GoDaddy guys said the primary domain is required to be hosted in order to create subdomains. BigRock guys said I can create subdomain and point it to the Wordpress.com blog.

I would like to know if it is possible. How?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Follow [this guide](https://en.support.wordpress.com/map-subdomain/), they key parts are copied below.

The gist of it is:

1. Add a CNAME record through the registrar where you purchased your domain or through your DNS provider.
2. Once the CNAME record has been added and verified, go to Domains and add the subdomain to your blog. This is done by clicking the blue Add Domain button in the upper right then clicking Map It button to the right of “Already own a domain?”. If everything is configured correctly, you will be prompted to pay for the upgrade and complete the mapping process.
3. After you have made your purchase, go to back to  Domains, if you’re not already there. Select your domain then click the Make Primary button in the upper right.

Please note, you may see a Redirect Loop error page if you immediately visit your site after setting a new Primary Domain. This is usually fixed within a few seconds by refreshing the page.

This guide was found on Google with the search "wordpress.com own domain subdomain".

Comment: I guess that is the part where I can map a subdomain to target my wordpress blog. My doubt is whether I can do this mapping while my primary domain is not hosted anywhere.

Comment: My best guess is not having the root domain hosted anywhere won't make a difference. DNS definitely doesn't care. When you make the DNS request it simply returns the IP of your target. Unless wordpress.com checks it should be fine. If it needs to be present just point it at Google or something. Give it a shot and report back.